# multiple File uploading in angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-forms

I am searching many sources for multiple file upload in angular 13 but I don't get any exact source I have to upload multiple files in form and the user can delete those files also after being selected. I write some code but I am cant getting upload multiple files to it I am sharing code with you

```js
export class CreateOrEditTooolModalComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('createOrEditModal', { static: true }) modal: ModalDirective;

    @Output() modalSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    active = false;
    saving = false;

    toool: CreateOrEditTooolDto = new CreateOrEditTooolDto();

    fileFileUploader: FileUploader;
    fileFileToken: string;
    fileFileName: string;
    fileFileAcceptedTypes: string = '';
    @ViewChild('Toool_fileLabel') toool_fileLabel: ElementRef;

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _tooolsServiceProxy: TooolsServiceProxy,
        private _dateTimeService: DateTimeService,
        private _tokenService: TokenService,
        private _http: HttpClient
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }

    show(tooolId?: number): void {
        if (!tooolId) {
            this.toool = new CreateOrEditTooolDto();
            this.toool.id = tooolId;

            this.fileFileName = null;

            this.active = true;
            this.modal.show();
        } else {
            this._tooolsServiceProxy.getTooolForEdit(tooolId).subscribe((result) => {
                this.toool = result.toool;

                this.fileFileName = result.fileFileName;

                this.active = true;
                this.modal.show();
            });
        }

        this.fileFileUploader = this.initializeUploader(
            AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/Toools/UploadfileFile',
            (fileToken) => (this.fileFileToken = fileToken)
        );
    }

    save(): void {
        this.saving = true;

        this.toool.fileToken = this.fileFileToken;

        this._tooolsServiceProxy
            .createOrEdit(this.toool)
            .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    this.saving = false;
                })
            )
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
                this.close();
                this.modalSave.emit(null);
            });
    }

    onSelectfileFile(fileInput: any): void {
        let selectedFile = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
        if (!selectedFile) {
            this.toool_fileLabel.nativeElement.innerText = this.l('ChooseAFile');
            return;
        }
        this.toool_fileLabel.nativeElement.innerText = selectedFile.name;
        this.fileFileUploader.clearQueue();
        this.fileFileUploader.addToQueue([selectedFile]);
        this.fileFileUploader.uploadAll();
    }

    removefileFile(): void {
        this.message.confirm(this.l('DoYouWantToRemoveTheFile'), this.l('AreYouSure'), (isConfirmed) => {
            if (isConfirmed) {
                this._tooolsServiceProxy.removefileFile(this.toool.id).subscribe(() => {
                    abp.notify.success(this.l('SuccessfullyDeleted'));
                    this.fileFileName = null;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    initializeUploader(url: string, onSuccess: (fileToken: string) => void): FileUploader {
        let uploader = new FileUploader({ url: url });

        let _uploaderOptions: FileUploaderOptions = {};
        _uploaderOptions.autoUpload = false;
        _uploaderOptions.authToken = 'Bearer ' + this._tokenService.getToken();
        _uploaderOptions.removeAfterUpload = true;

        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
            file.withCredentials = false;
        };

        uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status) => {
            const resp = <IAjaxResponse>JSON.parse(response);
            if (resp.success && resp.result.fileToken) {
                onSuccess(resp.result.fileToken);
            } else {
                this.message.error(resp.result.message);
            }
        };

        uploader.setOptions(_uploaderOptions);
        return uploader;
    }

    getDownloadUrl(id: string): string {
        return AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/File/DownloadBinaryFile?id=' + id;
    }

    close(): void {
        this.active = false;
        this.modal.hide();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._http.get(AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/toools/GetfileFileAllowedTypes').subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (!data || !data.result) {
                return;
            }

            let list = data.result as string[];
            if (list.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                this.fileFileAcceptedTypes += '.' + list[i] + ',';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">{{ l('file') }}</span>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input
        type="file"
        multiple
        class="custom-file-input"
        id="Toool_file"
        name="Toool_file"
        aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01"
        (change)="onSelectfileFile($event)"
        [accept]="fileFileAcceptedTypes"
      />
      <label class="custom-file-label" #Toool_fileLabel for="Toool_file">
        {{ l('ChooseAFile') }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="fileFileName" style="background-color: #e5e5e5; padding: 5px">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'CurrentFile' | localize }} :</span>
    <div class="alert alert-custom alert-white alert-bold m-1" role="alert">
      <div class="alert-text">
        <a href="{{ getDownloadUrl(toool.file) }}" target="_blank">{{ fileFileName }}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="alert-close">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="removefileFile()">
            <i class="la la-close fa-1x"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am sharing here my typescript class code in that I am created file name input name entity

Comment: Minor note, but `angularjs` isn't really an appropriate tag for Angular (2+) questions, they are completely separate technologies, effectively, despite the name.

Comment: On a more helpful note: Could you provide more details? Your question is around uploading files, but you have not included any of the code around actually doing the upload (`fileFileUploader`).

Comment: yes sure i am updating my code you can see know

Answer (score 0):

I'll just copy some chunks from an uploader component we have as an example. This component in particular has both drag&drop and file selection capabilities.

This won't be the full code, but will contain all the elements you need to get to the point of sending a request containing multiple files - you've made no mention of your back-end tech so I'll omit that part and assume you're able to receive that with no problem.

```
<input #fileSelector type="file" [multiple]="multiple" (change)="onFilesSelected($event.target.files)" hidden [accept]="accept">

<div *ngIf="!uploading" class="drop-container"
  [class.hovering]="isDragging"
  (click)="fileSelector.click()"
  (drop)="onDrop($event)"
  (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
  (dragleave)="stopDrag($event)"
  (dragend)="stopDrag($event)">

  <div class="icon"><fa-icon [icon]="iconUpload"></fa-icon></div>
  <div *ngIf="!hideText" class="text">Drag &amp; drop or click</div>
</div>
```

As you're using a standard file selection input, I'll only include that part of the component:

```
public onFilesSelected(files: File[]): void {
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const result: Array<File> = [];
    for (const file of files) {
      result.push(file);
    }
    
    this.emitFiles(result);        
}
```

As you can see from the last line, this is a reusable component and it emits the files that were selected for the parent to handle...

```
public onFileSelected(files: File[]) {
    if (!files || files.length === 0) return;

    this.selectedFile = files[0];
    this._uploadingFiles = true;

    this.service.upload(this.selectedFile, {
        some: 'extra',
        payload: 'information'
    });
}
```

Finally with the service actually sending the files:

```
public upload(file: File, request: FrSubmissionRequest) {
    const sub = this.http.upload<FrSubmissionResult>(this.uploadUrl, [file], request)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.isComplete) {
                sub.unsubscribe();
            }
            ServiceHelper.emit(this.uploadObs, response);
        });
}
```

That's a lie, it's not quite final because we use a wrapper for the `HttpClient`, and so from our particular component service, it uses the underlying wrapper http service...

We do a lot in our upload, handling progress %, etc. I think this small bit is the main think you'd care about to start with - just sending the request with the files attached:

```
/**
 * Upload files to the API - needs to be handled differently to standard posts.
 * Will append the files to the form data under the 'files' key.
 * @param {string} apiResource - API endpoint to hit, e.g. 'controller/action'
 * @param {File[]} files - Files to upload
 * @param {Object} body - Optional body content for the upload post; will be turned into form data
 */
public upload<TBody extends UploadResponseResult>(apiResource: string, files: File[], body?: Object): any {
    this.logger.verbose('HttpService.upload', this.logSystems);

    let url = this.constructUrl(apiResource);

    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach((file: File) => {
        formData.append('files', file, file.name);
    });

    if (body) {
        const encoded = this.encodePostBody(body);
        Object.keys(encoded).forEach((key: string) => formData.append(key, encoded[key]));
    }

    return this.httpClient.post(url, formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } // trigger header for the intercepter
        });
}
```